# how to continue code execution outside of a callback function?

Tags: jquery

I hope I'm using the right words to describe this problem.... Here I have defined an object called TK with a property and method.

```
var TK = {
    List: [],
    getSectionA: function(listName) {
        var arrayList = [];
        TK.returnList = $.get(
            'ajax/test.html', 
            { sendName: listName }, 
            function(data) {
            }
        );       
    }
};
```

calling the function

```
$("#dropDownList").change(function() {
    TK.getSectionA(fileName);
```

// Here I'm trying to get out of this callback function below and continue normal code execution after assigning the callback return data (resultLists) to a variable (TK.List) but when I alert the array variable TK.List, nothing is displayed.

```
TK.List = TK.returnList.done(function(data) {
    var resultLists = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        if (value == "false") {
            return false;
        }
        else if (value == "") {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            resultLists[index] = value;
        }
    });
    return resultLists;   
});
alert(TK.List.join("")) // not displaying
```

Comment: you can't, all code that needs access to data ***must*** be inside of the done callback.

Comment: Maybe you'd like [jQuery deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)?

Answer (score 0):

Just make `var resultLists = [];` as global.

Then set a timer after you call the AJAX. Once the timer expires, do

```
TK.List = resultsLists;
```

Or do something like this:

```
while(true){
    if(resultLists.length > 0) {
        break;
    }
}
TK.List = resultLists;
```

But make sure there is a local variable used inside the `$.each` loop and assigned to `resultLists` only at the end of loop.

Comment: What if the request takes longer than the timer?

Comment: If you do that, you mightaswell instead just do `async: false` and make it synchronous.

Comment: The while (resultLists.length) loop works when I adding an alert("hello") but does not work after replacing the alert hello with alert(Tk.List = resultLists);